# Issue in transferring EOS from Ledger Nano to exchange

Tags: eosio.token, resources

I was getting an issue at the time of transferring my EOS from Ledger Nano S using Fairy wallet to one exchange. It was unable to complete the transaction due to deadline. I got few good response and people told me to put some more EOS on stake to get more CPU resources to make my transaction successful.
I have a query that suppose I put 3 EOS on stake and transferred my EOS balances but how I will be able to transfer these 3 EOS which I put in stake as I will face the same issue in transfer of these 3 EOS so eventually I wont be able to transfer it even if I have it in my account.

Actually the real problem is that I want to change my ledger nano seeds so I need to transfer all my EOS from ledger nano to one exchange and then change the seeds and then transfer it back. I think I will lose these 3 EOS in this process. Do we have any other way so that I wont lose my EOS?

Comment: I have the same question! did you get any answers?

Answer (score 0):

There are websites that offer free transactions, such as bloks.io. You can use these websites to transfer your EOS to the exchange before changing your seeds.